# Plot bar chart from string

Tags: string, matlab, count

I want to create a bar graph showing the number eruptions for the respective countries. However, the data provided is in a string and I need to loop through the data set to count the respective countries. As it is in a string format, I am struggling to extract out the number of counts for each country in a loop. I managed to use strcmp and find, but the plot does not work. How do I create a loop which plots the chart sucessfully?

```
% Finding each individual country "eachcountry"
eachcountry = unique(thecountry);

% Counting the length of year for j

% loop through each index 
for j = 1:length(thecountry)

  A = strcmp('%s'eachcountry(j),thecountry);

  % Obtaining index of respective country
  indexcountry = find(A)

  numberofcounts =  numel(indexcountry);

  % Plotting with rectangle function, start from the first year, for x axis, 
  % start from 0 for y axis. Width is 1, while frequency is number of
  % counts.
  rectangle('Position',[eachcountry(j) 0 1 numberofcounts])

  hold on
 end

% Labelling axes
xlabel('Country')
ylabel('Frequency')
```

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a simple incrementor on each country. So label each new country (`Iceland == 1, Indonesia ==2` etc), and then make an array to count the eruptions, and just increment the number when an eruption has been found for the respective countries. Then in the end you can plot numeric data, and use the inverse flags (`1==Iceland, 2==Indonesia`) as labels on your plot.

Comment: Does the method described for 'Count of unique elements' in the matlab [documentation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/unique.html) for `unique` help?

Comment: you can also use the combo `[x,~,ind] = unique(thecountry)` and `N = histcounts(ind,1:length(x))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`categorical`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/categorical.html) data type serves to provide you this behaviour directly. All you should need is

```
histogram(categorical(thecountry));

% Labelling axes
xlabel('Country')
ylabel('Frequency')
```